# MariaDB 10.5 slower than mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Since i moved from mysql 5.5 to mariadb 10.5 queries much slower even with many different tuning config and new server is ssd but old mysql was faster did anyone has such experience ?

even with simple BENCHMARK mysql 5.5 is faster

> SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000,AES_ENCRYPT('hello','goodbye'));

mysql 5.5 is 0.25 to 0.30 sec vs mariaDB is 0.44 to 0.55 sec

```
[mysqld]
user                            = mysql
port                            = 7999
basedir                         = /usr
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir                 = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
bind-address                    = *

key_buffer_size                 = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 4M
max_allowed_packet              = 1G
wait_timeout                    = 86400
interactive_timeout             = 86400
net_read_timeout                = 120
net_write_timeout               = 120
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP
max_length_for_sort_data        = 8192
query_cache_limit               = 0
query_cache_size                = 0
query_cache_type                = 0
expire_logs_days                = 10
max_binlog_size                 = 100M
max_connections                 = 20000
back_log                        = 4096
open_files_limit                = 20240
innodb_open_files               = 20240
max_connect_errors              = 3072
table_open_cache                = 4096
table_definition_cache          = 4096
tmp_table_size                  = 1G
max_heap_table_size             = 1G

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 100G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 10
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
performance_schema              = 0
innodb-file-per-table           = 1
innodb_io_capacity              = 20000
innodb_table_locks              = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 5
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M

sql_mode                        = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_warnings                    = 2


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet              = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size                 = 16M
```

Comment: Obviously benchmark of `AES_ENCRYPT` won't be impacted by SSD. I did look and mysql-5.6 mysql-5.7 and mysql-8.0 all experienced a similar slowdown which might be explained by the openssl library version. I assume this isn't your workload, so I recommend showing some `EXPLAIN {query}` differences. Try [analyze tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-table/) to see if improved tables stats result in faster queries.

Comment: @danblack Not only AES_ENCRYPT even simple (1+1) sql 5.5 is faster i tried to set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'; its now better but still 5.5 was faster :(

Comment: Additional MariaDB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide observations/suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck 2x E5-2660 v2 + 128G Ram + 480 SSD + Server is not loaded just some tables has over 140k rows; Logs (without SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;) [here](https://easyupload.io/s4ud2b)

Comment: @m0hamedessam  Please post your TEXT data to justpaste.it as requested.  If SHOW GLOBAL STATUS is not included, we have NOTHING to analyze for workload analysis.  Not interested in your dlownload for IO DRIVER updates to my system.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry for delay i was waiting 24h pass here's what you ask for 
[https://justpaste.it/3jt93](https://justpaste.it/3jt93) ;) [https://justpaste.it/1qslv](https://justpaste.it/1qslv) ;) [https://justpaste.it/9parh](https://justpaste.it/9parh) ;) https://justpaste.it/2ujaz ;) [https://justpaste.it/5a1u1](https://justpaste.it/5a1u1) thanks for your help hope find out any tune options to fix this.

Comment: @m0hamedessam  Thanks for your posted data.  Is this a public access website?  Could you share the URL?  Do you know why there are about 1,400 Sleeping process id's?  Could we Skype TALK?  My Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com  in GMT -5 hours (same time as Chicago, USA).

Comment: @WilsonHauck added on skype :)

Comment: @m0hamedessam  Thanks for your contact via Skype.  3 more TEXT details would be helpful, if posted to  justpaste.it   A) from your 5.5.62 instance, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  after minimum 24 hours of uptime.  B) from 5.5.62 OS Command Prompt, ulimit -a  report of os limits.  and C) from 10.5.16 Debian Linux Command Prompt,  ulimit -a  report of os limits.  Thank you, Wilson

Comment: @m0hamedessam  Are you still interested in making 10.5 perform as well as 5.5 version?